# calling async function recursively in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, recursion

I am new to node.js.Learning async library,currently I have array of urls.For each url,I have to make a request to some website and from that website I will get its hyperlinks from html page.So we I have to make a call recursively with request.js module of Node.js.

```
var urls=["http://www.a.com","http://www.b.com"];

function getUrls(url,cb){

    request(url,function(error,response,body){

        if(response && response.statusCode==200)
        {


        }

        cb();
    });
}

function startProcess(urls){

    async.map(urls,getUrls,function(error,data){

    })

}
startProcess(urls);
```

In getUrls function,I have called request function each time for each url.When I am getting html page data from response.I am scraping urls from that page also..I want to call "request" function for those urls also recursively.

Can it be done without async.map function ?

Comment: Please, specify more carefully, where do you want to "proceed". What does not work exactly?

Comment: @SergeyYarotskiy Editted the qquestion

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You will get stack overflow after some iteration. What you should do to solve this task, is to maintain queue of urls, which you want to scrape. Then on each successful response add new url into this queue. Something like this:

```
let queue = ['https://some.start.point.net'];
const concurrency = 5;
let activeThreads = 0

async function scraper(url) {
    activeThreads++;
    const body = await request.get(url);
    const urls = // parse body here
    for (const url of urls) queue.push(url);
    activeThreads--;
}

setInterval(() => {
    if (activeThreads < concurrency && queue.length) scraper(queue.shift());
}, 10)
```

Comment: thanks... can u provide me with some good links for better explanation to async functions and await ?

Comment: I am not getting html body in return of request.get(url)...How can I get the html body... thanks in advance

Comment: Ask different question about async / await. Also check `request` documentation to see what returned (it returns response object with status code, body, headers, etc), or just use debugger with breakpoints.